# Как указать уровень сжатия видео?

Tags: c++, opencv

```
cvCreateVideoWriter("d:\\test.avi", CV_FOURCC('X', 'V', 'I', 'D'), FPS, size, 1);
```

Если вместо `CV_FOURCC('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')` указать `-1`, то можно выбрать кодек и уровень сжатия.

При указании `CV_FOURCC('X', 'V', 'I', 'D')` сожмется с рекомендуемыми настройками.

Как программно указать уровень сжатия?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по исходникам OpenCV для VFW, то никак. Диалог вызывается в файле `cap_vfw.cpp` в строке за номером 783 функцией `AVISaveOptions()`. Обозначенный вызов производится в методе `createStreams()` класса `CvVideoWriter_VFW`.

```
if( AVIFileCreateStream( avifile, &uncompressed, &aviinfo ) == AVIERR_OK )
{
    AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS copts, *pcopts = &copts;
    copts.fccType = streamtypeVIDEO;
    copts.fccHandler = fourcc != -1 ? fourcc : 0;
    copts.dwKeyFrameEvery = 1;
    copts.dwQuality = 10000;
    copts.dwBytesPerSecond = 0;
    copts.dwFlags = AVICOMPRESSF_VALID;
    copts.lpFormat = &bmih;
    copts.cbFormat = (isColor ? sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) : sizeof(bmih));
    copts.lpParms = 0;
    copts.cbParms = 0;
    copts.dwInterleaveEvery = 0;

    if( fourcc != -1 || AVISaveOptions( 0, 0, 1, &uncompressed, &pcopts ) == TRUE )
    {
        if( AVIMakeCompressedStream( &compressed, uncompressed, pcopts, 0 ) == AVIERR_OK &&
            AVIStreamSetFormat( compressed, 0, &bmih, sizeof(bmih)) == AVIERR_OK )
        {
            fps = fps;
            fourcc = (int)copts.fccHandler;
            frameSize = frameSize;
            tempFrame = cvCreateImage( frameSize, 8, (isColor ? 3 : 1) );
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Как хорошо видно, даже если `fourcc` будет равна значению `-1`, но при этом `AVISaveOptions()` выдаст "истину" (скорее всего означает, что пользователь в диалоге нажмёт `ОК`), то условие сработает и опции, выбранные в диалоге должны записаться в параметры видеопотока. Почему это не происходит по отношению к уровню сжатия - вопрос остаётся открытый, однако `AVISaveOptions()` принадлежит к API операционной системы и не контролируется, собственно, OpenCV.

Можно было бы хардкодом после вызова `AVISaveOptions()` указать нужное значение (скорее всего это `dwQuality` у `AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS`), но это уже будет правка исходников OpenCV, после чего последний придётся пересобирать, чтобы изменения вступили в силу.

Comment: нашли новый баг в `opencv`? (улыбка)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin , я не думаю, что это баг OpenCV, во всяком случае код не выглядит неправильным. Тут скорее проблема в `AVISaveOptions()`. Функция со старого API работы с видео, ещё того, что был до DirectShow, поэтому может просто уже начала проявляться несовместимость. Не знаю.